# Apt errors since upgrade to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apt, updates

I have been searching for a while for solutions and have found [this][1]. But since there is no feedback from the thread-starter and this isn't the solution to me, i want to ask again.

I have update to Ubuntu 12.04 and i am using the Gnome 3 desktop. After the Update i had a couple of error messages from apport-gtk (or from apport about gtk?!?). Submitting the error logs gave me some more errors.

The system works now but every time I am using apt or aptitude i get the following messages.

```
wowa@wowapc:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.99ubuntu13) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic (3.2.0-24.37) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.2.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.2.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.2.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.2.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-runlilo 3.2.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic
Fatal: No images have been defined.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-runlilo exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.2.0.24.26); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                        No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                            update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic
Fatal: No images have been defined.
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//runlilo exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I hope anyone can help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is due to a conflict with the `lilo` package, which appears to be installed on your system.  The default boot loader for Ubuntu is `Grub2`, you probably don't need `lilo`.

Try `sudo apt-get remove lilo`.  Then try, eg. `sudo dpkg --configure initramfs-tools`.  The error messages should go away.

Comment: It helped. this was apparently the solution. Thank you very much!!!!