# Error while updating my system 16.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, package-management, kernel, dpkg

When I am using following command to update my system, I got an error from dpkg,how to rectify that,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

linux-signed-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-generic:
 linux-signed-generic depends on linux-signed-image-generic (= 4.4.0.24.25); however:
  Package linux-signed-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-signed-image-4.4.0-24-generic
 linux-signed-image-generic
 linux-signed-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apt errors since upgrade to 12.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/130266/apt-errors-since-upgrade-to-12-04)

Answer (score -1):

Follow this answer. I had the same problem and after delete lilo helps me
[Apt errors since upgrade to 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130266/apt-errors-since-upgrade-to-12-04)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.